# Spring @Bean factory method invoked ahead of @Value variable being resolved

Tags: spring, configuration, javabeans

I'm having an issue with the order resolution of Spring Java/XML configuration.  It seems that the `@Value` annotations are not being resolved ahead of `@Bean` factory methods being invoked, specifically when loading properties from external XML configuration.

This is a condensed version of what I'm doing:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:configurable-context.xml"})
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("#{myProps['my.custom.key']}")
    private String someValue = null;

    @Bean
    public SomeObject someObject() {
        return new SomeObject(someValue);   // Fails because someValue == null
    }
}
```

and this is configurable-context.xml :

```
...
<util:map id="myProps">
    <entry key="my.custom.key" value="myVal"/>
</util:map>
...
```

The issue is that the `someObject(...)` factory method is invoked ahead of the `@Value` annotation being evaluated for `someValue`, so this is `null` at the time.

Any thoughts on how I can force resolution of the `someValue` variable ahead of the factory method being invoked?

**Update**
As inspired by response from @Ekem, this code worked for me using XML sourced properties:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:configurable-context.xml"})
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Resource(name = "myProps")
    private Properties myProps;

    @Bean
    public SomeObject someObject() {
        return new SomeObject(myProps.getProperty("my.custom.key"));    // Now works :-)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your configuration as follows so that myProps bean is initialized first

@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:configurable-context.xml"})

```
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("#{myProps['my.custom.key']}")
    private String someValue = null;

    @Bean
    @DependOn("myProps")
    public SomeObject someObject() {
        return new SomeObject(someValue);  
    }
}
```

Alternatively to make your configuration clean use of the environment abstraction as follows

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    public class SecurityConfig {

            @Autowired
            private private Environment env;

            @Bean
            public SomeObject someObject() {
                return new SomeObject(env.getProperty("my.custom.key"));  
            }
        }
```

Then add an application.properties file to the root of your classpath with an entry my.custom.key=myVal
This will eliminate the need for an xml application context just to define a hardcoded property

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to avoid using a properties file if possible -- at least for now we have good reason to preserve XML. I couldn't get your `@DependsOn` solution to work, but it inspired the solution posted above.